# mouseenter and mouseleave only works with the first element

Tags: php, jquery

i am fetching this data from database :

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM articles WHERE uid='".$uid."'";
$res = mysql_query($sql) or die (mysql_error());

if (mysql_num_rows($res) > 0) {

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) {
        $article_id = $row['id'];
        $author = $row['author'];
        $article_name = $row['article_name'];
        $num_views = $row['num_views'];
        $rate = $row['rate'];
        $times_rated = $row['times_rated'];
        $edit_time = $row['edit_time'];
        echo "<div id='list_articles'>";
        echo "<a class='normal_link' href='view_article.php?id=".$article_id."'>".$article_name."</a>";
        echo "<span class='del' id='".$article_id."'>x</span>";
        echo "</div>";
    }
```

And i am using this code to hide the span with class del :

```
.del {
    float:right;
    width:10px;
    text-align:center;
    color:#3B581E;
    border:1px solid #3B581E;
    display:none;
}
```

What i am trying to do is to view the spad with class "del" whenever i `mouseenter` the div with id  `list_articles` and to hide the same span whenever i `mouseleave` the div , I am using this jquery code for that :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#list_articles').mouseenter(function(){
        $('span', this).show();
    }).mouseleave(function(){
        $('span', this).hide();
    });
});
```

The effect seems to work but only with the first result on my page and does not work with the rest of the divs below , Any idea ??

thanks for help :)

Comment: do not use id use class instead

Comment: Worked perfectly , But i do not understand why it is now working if if i use id , I am already using $(this) to identify the targeted element.

Comment: You should only ever have one instance of an ID on the page. If there is to be more than one use a class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
echo "<div id='list_articles' class="listArticles">";

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.listArticles').mouseenter(function(){
        $('span', this).show();
    }).mouseleave(function(){
        $('span', this).hide();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

`id`s should be unique - you should add / change it to a class and then bind your events to the class - this will bind all DOM elements with that class to your events.

PHP :

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) {
        $article_id = $row['id'];
        $author = $row['author'];
        $article_name = $row['article_name'];
        $num_views = $row['num_views'];
        $rate = $row['rate'];
        $times_rated = $row['times_rated'];
        $edit_time = $row['edit_time'];
        echo "<div class='list_articles'>";   /// Updated - changed id to class
        echo "<a class='normal_link' href='view_article.php?id=".$article_id."'>".$article_name."</a>";
        echo "<span class='del' id='".$article_id."'>x</span>";
        echo "</div>";
    }
```

JavaScript :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.list_articles') // changed the selector
        ...
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

use list_articles as a class instead of id because elements with same id did not work properly